# Culture is not supported 1033 (0x0409)

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, alpine-linux, icu

i am using dotnet 2.2 image to run my service application at environment: docker windows (linux container)

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine AS build-env
```

and hitting below error:

System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.| Parameter name: culture| 1033 (0x0409) is an invalid culture identifier.

i have set following at docker file. build without problem but still error displayed when application is running

```html
# Set the locale
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
```

Comment: The error says you tried to use Latin1 instead of UTF8, even though the locale settings say UTF8. The *real* fix would be to make sure you use the correct encoding. If you really want to use Latin1, install the appropriate codepage package and disable the invariant globalization mode.

Comment: I am not sure how to install additional code page, I'm using docker provided by Microsoft, dotnet.

Comment: Do you *want* Latin 1 or not? If you don't expect to have to use Latin 1, you won't need to install any codepage. That's controlled by *your* code, not the environment. Where was this exception thrown? What is the *full* exception text, returned by `Exception.ToString()` ?

Comment: It could be that there's a bug in a package you used that tries to use `en-US` explicitly. Or your own code may have tried to use `GetCultureInfo("en-US")` instead of `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: In any case, you have to post your code so people can try to reproduce the problem. If I created a simple console app in WSL which called `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")` I'd expect to get an error. Is it that simple though?

Comment: actually i could not find which line in the application codes (not docker dotnet image) uses locale (neither en-US or latin), only saw one line about "Culture=neutral" in log file. the nlog.config uses "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>" , not sure if this is the "culture" being blocked.. the ICU installed (displayed at console) is Installing icu-libs (64.2-r0) . this is more like trial and error, as when without this line of icu, another error prompted....

Comment: without ICU pkg, error "Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works.

updating the solution:
i have run the same docker image at teamcity , linux based environement and the extra lines to define codepage is not needed at all.

so this issue is only happend at docker windows (linux container) run at Windows 10.

```html
# Disable the invariant mode (set in base image)
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs

ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: What this does, is enable the use of other codepages even though the locale explicitly says that UTF8 is used. Is that what you really want? The ICU libraries are already installed in most distros, except RHEL 6. Which one are you using?

Comment: The environment is docker Linux container run under windows 10.

Comment: Which says nothing about the actual distribution. Did you use Ubuntu, Kali, Debian? The ICU libraries are required for codepage support in general, not just for .NET Core. If you want to use UTF8 though, you *don't* need them

Comment: as i mentioned at main post, docker image downloaded "FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine AS build-env" and running inside docker linux container from docker windows at my windows 10 machine. perhaps you need to understand more about docker and container and windows environment ? @PanagiotisKanavos , are you familiar with docker windows running linux container? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers